# Find extrema of quadratic problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, matrix-calculus, quadratic-programming

I have to find the extrema of the following function:

$f(x) = x'Hx + c'x$,

where $x'$ means the transpose. Moreover, $x,c \in \Re^n$ and $H \in \Re^{nxn}$. The matrix $H$ does not have any special property.

If I consider it as a *function*, I can compute the gradient and set it equal to zero:

$x = -(H+H')^{-1}c$,

and this is the (vector of?) stationary point. But how do I procede further? I can compute the Hessian ($H+H'$), but then?
Thank you.

Comment: When you're given $f$, aren't you also given $\mathrm H$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No, it is purely general. Nothing else. Thanks

Comment: Then write the quadratic form. There. You have $\dfrac{\mathrm H + \mathrm H^\top}{2}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am sorry but I do not understand: what is it useful for? Thank you.

Comment: If you are considering a general quadratic function, then you cannot proceed further. Also, I wouldn't invert the matrix. Just solve the linear system.